# How to download just the blockheaders for the blockchain

Tags: bitcoind, block-header, raw-data

I'd like to download all the blockheaders for the blockchain directly from the network (not an external API) ... what is the best way to do this?

I don't actually care about the transaction data and have no need for it, specifically, I need the difficulty level at each block, along with the timestamp. I know there are API's etc. to get this information but I specifically do not want to do that for my use case. I would not like to run the entire bitcoind service locally (there is too much overhead downloading the whole chain, verifying it etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You can make it with [getheaders](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#getheaders) p2p message, will return headers of blocks in a range.
Remember of [handshaking](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#version) and setting tx-relay to false.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm looking for. Is there a C++ library that could handle sending/receiving the data?