Download block headers only in Bitcoin Core?
Is there a way in Bitcoin Core to just download all the block headers and not the blocks themselves?

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/111850/how-to-download-just-the-blockheaders-for-the-blockchain

@Lee Thanks. So Electrum can do it. What about Bitcoin Core?

There is no such feature in Bitcoin Core today.
